# How to forbid port-forwarding for a password protected SSH user?

Tags: ssh, password, git, port-forwarding

### Brief:

I would like to restrict port-forwarding from an SSH user identified by password.

### Explanation:

In the following explanation of how to install a `git` server:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

They explain that an SSH user with limited or no shell access could still use port-forwarding and some other OS services.

> At this point, users are still able to use SSH port forwarding to
>   access any host the git server is able to reach.

In this same text, they solve the problem by restricting SSH access in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` using `no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty`.

I would like to do the same using password identification: I know that asymmetric cryptographic keys are usually more secure than password, but it also prevent accessing a server from "anywhere" without having your private key in the pocket.

It seems (to me) that `authorized_keys` only applies to ssl key identification and not to password.

**How to limit port forwarding when using password identification?**

Note: Using CentOS 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the same in [sshd.config](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/sshd_config/#port-forwarding) but you need to disable shell access, because they still can run their own sshd [see this question](https://superuser.com/questions/229743/howto-disable-ssh-local-port-forwarding)

```
AllowTcpForwarding no
AllowStreamLocalForwarding no
GatewayPorts no
PermitTunnel no
```

Comment: Thank you. I will also look git-credentials.